# Tomcat Version 7, unable to log in

Tags: tomcat7

In my tomcat-users.xml, I have

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="pass" roles='admin-gui,manager-gui'/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` using the username and password, it does not log me in. The same authentication box appears again.

Comment: Strange, I've tried it using the exact same content in tomcat-users.xml and it works for me in my Ubuntu box. What is your environment ? How did you deploy Tomcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your roles in double quotes:

```
<user username="admin" password="pass" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it was necessary to restart the tomcat server and restart/close/reopen the browser after changing the tomcat-user.xml.

This then worked.

when restarting the tomcat server I use the ./shutdown.sh wait a couple of seconds then use the ./startup.sh from the tomcat bin directory.  This gives the server a chance to reload.